# using pl/sql external package and getting error with declaration

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I need to run a procedure in a package external to my script.  The script is in an APEX page:

```
begin 
   idsud.segyload.loaddataset(p_dataset_id => :p40_dset, p_mode => 'INIT'); 
end;
```

When I try to use this I get an error saying that I must declare the "idsud.segyload" package. How to do this?

Comment: What does your procedure do? Do you need to assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the appropriate permissions?

e.g.    `GRANT EXECUTE ON idsud.segyload TO {apex_schema};`